# is it possible to apply LableHeaderView on vertical header of QtableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have tried to apply LabelHeaderView on a QtableWidget for vertical headers which takes Qlabel as a header item, it works for table with horizontal headers but does not work for table with vertical headers.So, how to add Qlabel on vertical header of QtableWidget with the help of this class LabelHeaderView?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HeaderProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_Header:
            option.text = ""
        super(HeaderProxyStyle, self).drawControl(
            element, option, painter, widget
        )


class LabelHeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self.m_labels = []
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        self.sectionCountChanged.connect(self.onSectionCountChanged)
        self.parent().horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.adjustPositions
        )
        proxy_style = HeaderProxyStyle(self.style())
        self.setStyle(proxy_style)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onSectionCountChanged(self):
        while self.m_labels:
            label = self.m_labels.pop()
            label.deleteLater()
        for i in range(self.count()):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.m_labels.append(label)
            self.update_data()
            self.adjustPositions()

    def setModel(self, model):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).setModel(model)
        if self.model() is not None:
            self.model().headerDataChanged.connect(self.update_data)

    def update_data(self):
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionHeader()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        for i, label in enumerate(self.m_labels):
            text = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
            )
            label.setText(str(text))
            pal = label.palette()
            bc = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole
            )
            if bc is None:
                bc = option.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.Window)
            pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Window, bc)

            fc = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole
            )
            if fc is None:
                fc = option.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText)
            pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, fc)

            label.setPalette(pal)

            textAlignment = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole
            )
            if textAlignment is None:
                textAlignment = self.defaultAlignment()
            label.setAlignment(textAlignment)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def adjustPositions(self):
        for index, label in enumerate(self.m_labels):
            geom = QtCore.QRect(
                self.sectionViewportPosition(index),
                0,
                self.sectionSize(index),
                self.height(),
            )
            geom.adjust(2, 0, -2, 0)
            label.setGeometry(geom)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
    header = LabelHeaderView(w)
    w.setVerticalHeader(header)

    header_labels = []
    for i in range(w.columnCount()):
        header_label = "<sub>%s</sub><b>Header</b><sup>%s</sup>" % (i, i)
        header_labels.append(header_label)
    w.setVerticalHeaderLabels(header_labels)

    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried with vertical header, but forgot to edit the code during posting the question.The code has now been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the geometric calculations and the orientation of the QHeaderView:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HeaderProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_Header:
            option.text = ""
        super(HeaderProxyStyle, self).drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)


class LabelHeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).__init__(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent)
        self.m_labels = []
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        self.sectionCountChanged.connect(self.onSectionCountChanged)
        self.parent().horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        proxy_style = HeaderProxyStyle(self.style())
        self.setStyle(proxy_style)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onSectionCountChanged(self):
        while self.m_labels:
            label = self.m_labels.pop()
            label.deleteLater()
        for i in range(self.count()):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.m_labels.append(label)
            self.update_data()
            self.adjustPositions()

    def setModel(self, model):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).setModel(model)
        if self.model() is not None:
            self.model().headerDataChanged.connect(self.update_data)

    def update_data(self):
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionHeader()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        for i, label in enumerate(self.m_labels):
            text = self.model().headerData(i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            label.setText(str(text))
            pal = label.palette()
            bc = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole
            )
            if bc is None:
                bc = option.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.Window)
            pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Window, bc)

            fc = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole
            )
            if fc is None:
                fc = option.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText)
            pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, fc)

            label.setPalette(pal)

            textAlignment = self.model().headerData(
                i, self.orientation(), QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole
            )
            if textAlignment is None:
                textAlignment = self.defaultAlignment()
            label.setAlignment(textAlignment)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super(LabelHeaderView, self).updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def adjustPositions(self):
        w = -1
        for index, label in enumerate(self.m_labels):
            geom = QtCore.QRect(
                0,
                self.sectionViewportPosition(index),
                label.sizeHint().width(),
                self.sectionSize(index),
            )
            w = geom.width() if w == -1 else max(w, geom.width())
            geom.adjust(0, 2, 0, -2)
            label.setGeometry(geom)
        self.setFixedWidth(w + 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
    header = LabelHeaderView(w)
    w.setVerticalHeader(header)

    header_labels = []
    for i in range(w.columnCount()):
        header_label = "<sub>%s</sub><b>Header</b><sup>%s</sup>" % (i, i)
        header_labels.append(header_label)
    w.setVerticalHeaderLabels(header_labels)

    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```